# Segregation of numerical results from a single text file to multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, piping

I have a data like this

```
#start
#gatherData
*ELEMENT_SHELL
48709       1   50614   50616   50618   50613
48710       1   50613   50618   50608   50609
48711       1   50616   50617   50619   50618
48712       1   50618   50619   50607   50608
48715       1   50589   50590   50620   50615
48716       1   50615   50620   50616   50614
48717       1   50590   50591   50621   50620
48721       1   50623   50625   50626   50622
48722       1   50622   50626   50610   50611
48723       1   50625   50614   50613   50626
*END
$PresentData
$RESULT OF strength
48709  1.0267261e-002
48710  1.0721873e-002
48711  1.1930415e-002
48712  1.2186395e-002
48715  9.7443219e-003
48716  1.0036242e-002
48717  1.1186538e-002
48721  7.9333931e-003
48722  8.6850608e-003
48723  8.9872172e-003
```

What I want to do is to check first of all the results under 
$RESULT OF strength

which numbers in the second column lie between 0 and 1e-002, then based on that search the number between *ELEMENT_SHELL AND *END and send the complete line to new text file test1.txt. If the number is between 1e-002 to 1e-003 to the next text file test2.txt and segregate this single file into two different files. 
Text1.text would have

```
48709       1   50614   50616   50618   50613
48710       1   50613   50618   50608   50609
48711       1   50616   50617   50619   50618
48712       1   50618   50619   50607   50608
48716       1   50615   50620   50616   50614
48717       1   50590   50591   50621   50620
```

Text2.txt would have

```
48721       1   50623   50625   50626   50622
48722       1   50622   50626   50610   50611
48723       1   50625   50614   50613   50626
48715       1   50589   50590   50620   50615
```

Can any expert suggest the way with SED, or AWk? I think final results could be piped easily but the segregation from the same file and find it again is problematic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following commands (assuming that the source file is `txt.txt`:

```
grep "$RESULT OF strength" -A1000 txt.txt | awk '$2>0.01' | cut -f 1 | xargs -I{} grep {} txt.txt | egrep "[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+1[[:blank:]]+" > test1.txt


grep "$RESULT OF strength" -A1000 txt.txt | awk '$2<0.01' | cut -f 1 | xargs -I{} grep {} txt.txt | egrep "[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+1[[:blank:]]+" > test2.txt
```

If the columns are separated by spaces, then it would be:

```
grep "$RESULT OF strength" -A1000 txt.txt | sed 's/[\s]{2,}/\t/g' | awk '$2>0.01' | cut -f 1 -d' ' | xargs -I{} grep {} txt.txt | egrep "[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+1[[:blank:]]+" > test1.txt

grep "$RESULT OF strength" -A1000 txt.txt | sed 's/[\s]{2,}/\t/g' | awk '$2<0.01' | cut -f 1 -d' ' | xargs -I{} grep {} txt.txt | egrep "[0-9]+[[:blank:]]+1[[:blank:]]+" > test2.txt
```

Comment: it doesnt return any thing to the new file.

Comment: it works on my debian... anyway, try to change `[[:blank:]]` for `[ \t]` just in case... And of course, change `txt.txt` (all occurrences) for your filename...

Comment: the file is again empty. As far as I understand, you read of complete text under "$Result OF strength " and then sort it..  can you please please explain what is what?  I will then be able to sort it out. Since its a one liner I dont understand it to use it line by line and see the output. It would be very helpful. thanks

Comment: yes, the line gets the lines after "$RESULT OF strength" (up to 1000) in file "txt.txt", then it gets the ones that second column is greater or less than 0.01, then you keep only the ID's (getting the first column of cut) and finally you look for this ID's on the full file.

Comment: maybe the problem is field separators... is there tabs or spaces between columns?

Comment: it is spaces and cut -f 1 is suitbale for tabs, may be that is the reason though I tried it with -d ' ' too but didnt work. is it possible for you to break down the code in singles and comment for understanding too? I have taken a long way to solve the problem by changing the code after cut and use of awk.

Comment: I've edited the answer to work with space separation (at least 2). Just replaced the spaces with tabs using `sed` ... Can you try it?

Comment: its works for my purpose now. I just get some unwanted text lines in between but I will solve it with sed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

As a basic solution, consider the following code:

```
[hamadhassan $] cat tri.awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f 

BEGIN{
    load_state=1; 
}


$0=="$RESULT OF strength"{
#    print "end of load state"
    load_state=0;
}

load_state==1 && NF==6{
#    print "storing "$0
    lut[$1]=$0; # store line in look up table:
}

load_state==0 && NF==2{
    if($2>0.0 && $2<1e-2){
    if($1 in lut){
        print lut[$1] > "Text2.txt";
    }
    }else{
    if($1 in lut){
        print lut[$1] > "Text1.txt";
    }
    }

}
[hamadhassan $]
```

which given your sample input:

```
[hamadhassan $] cat test.in
#start
#gatherData
*ELEMENT_SHELL
48709       1   50614   50616   50618   50613
48710       1   50613   50618   50608   50609
48711       1   50616   50617   50619   50618
48712       1   50618   50619   50607   50608
48715       1   50589   50590   50620   50615
48716       1   50615   50620   50616   50614
48717       1   50590   50591   50621   50620
48721       1   50623   50625   50626   50622
48722       1   50622   50626   50610   50611
48723       1   50625   50614   50613   50626
*END
$PresentData
$RESULT OF strength
48709  1.0267261e-002
48710  1.0721873e-002
48711  1.1930415e-002
48712  1.2186395e-002
48715  9.7443219e-003
48716  1.0036242e-002
48717  1.1186538e-002
48721  7.9333931e-003
48722  8.6850608e-003
48723  8.9872172e-003[hamadhassan $]
```

gives:

```
[hamadhassan $] ./tri.awk test.in
[hamadhassan $] cat Text2.txt
48715       1   50589   50590   50620   50615
48721       1   50623   50625   50626   50622
48722       1   50622   50626   50610   50611
48723       1   50625   50614   50613   50626
[hamadhassan $] cat Text1.txt
48709       1   50614   50616   50618   50613
48710       1   50613   50618   50608   50609
48711       1   50616   50617   50619   50618
48712       1   50618   50619   50607   50608
48716       1   50615   50620   50616   50614
48717       1   50590   50591   50621   50620
[hamadhassan $]
```

This was on CenTOS 6 with awk 3.1.7.

Comment: it gives unfortunately an error ./scr.sh: line 7: BEGIN{: command not found. It may be due to version, can you please suggest an edit? I am using   x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: and the result should be different as I mentioned in my question the last two highlighted blocks, thanks

Comment: the shebang needs to be the first thing in the file. Make sure you have no spaces or new lines before it (#!/usr/bin/gawk -f )